# PHP Call to member function toXML

Tags: php

```
<?php
require_once('spell-check-library.php');
$content = "Hello";
 $options = array(
  "lang"                    => 'en',
"maxSuggestions"        => 10,
"customDict"            => 0,
"charset"               => 'utf-8'
);
$factory = new SpellChecker($options);

$spell = $factory->create(trim("Ths is a tst"));

header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
echo $spell->toXML();
?>
```

I used this code and im getting this error

Fatal error: Call to a member function toXML() on a non-object in /home/ubuntu/workspace/include/checker.php on line 15

Call Stack:
    0.0003     232720   1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/include/checker.php:0

How do i fix it

Comment: you figure out why $spell is null.

Comment: Or rather, why it isn't an object.

Comment: @JonStirling lol ... yes, i just showed all how i get into that snake pit. The end result would be the same though. Fortunately, i have good logging and debug capabilities on my dev platform, makes it much easier to debug than resorting to a Q on SO.

Answer (score 0):

factory failed to create object spell, maybe you need to check param of create first